# Sync Linux Centos 7 Directory With Dropbox in realtime

Tags: synchronization, dropbox

I do have Linux Centos 7 Server which i would like to sync specific directory with `dropbox` in realtime.

For example, let's say that i do have directory `A` which is located in `/var/www/html/A/`

I would like to sync that directory `A` with `dropbox` in realtime.

i already registered an account with `dropbox` but i don't know how to start the configuration now.

could you please address me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install Dropbox on CentOS 7. As of late 2018, Dropbox requires Glibc 2.18.

CentOS 7 is packaged with Glib 2.17. Upgrading glibc is not recommended.

If you really need Dropbox on Linux, I think Ubuntu ships with glibc 2.18+.

Comment: any recommendation regarding similar  application to do the task on Centos 7?

Comment: You mean a similar service? Or another way to sync with Dropbox?

Comment: similar service